# I want to download and use Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

Is it possible for someone to send me the DVD to download Ubuntu or is there any other way?

Comment: Hi! And welcome to AskUbuntu! We are glad that you want to try Ubuntu, but you shouldn't give your address to the public. Anyway, you can easily get Ubuntu by yourself. Just buy a black DVD or a USB stick and download the last Ubuntu version on it. There are plenty of tutorials on web and AskUbuntu is here with lots of answers. Here's the download link https://www.ubuntu.com/download .

Answer (score 4):

You asked the question so I'll give you the answer. Be warned that Linux is a system for those that are willing to read and educate themselves. If you don't try to learn anything before you ask a question, you're going to irritate people in any forum, about any subject. After you learn, you should always pay it forward.

1. Sending a DVD costs time and money.
2. Reading is only your time, and in the end, it saves you more time because you'll know how to over come a problem when you encounter it.
3. The resources on the internet are widely available to teach you, if you read.

Go [Ubuntu Downloads](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and read the page on alternative downloading or switching systems. Read up on getting a bootable usb flash drive.